# What Datum is used by Google Maps?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, google-maps, datum

I am trying to convert vector shapefiles into Google Maps Datum using QGIS.

Do you know which one is the datum?

When I tried to convert them into WGS84 EPSG 3857, I could see that the shapes of the buildings didn't fit very well with those which are in Maps.

---

I've already tried using both EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326. I don't have any good results.[image]

Comment: try EPSG 4326 WGS84 World Aux

Comment: Sorry, I've already tried.. and it doesn't work. I mean the shapes don't fit as well.

Comment: what datum is your shapefile in? are you sure they're accurate?

Comment: I saved the shapefiles in EPSG:3857 and EPSG:4326 CRS.

Comment: Once again: Are you sure your shapefiles are accurate?

Comment: ... and don't expect the Google Earth Orthoimagery to be georeferenced "accurately". Sometimes they aren't even "ortho". You get what you paid for ...

Comment: The Shapefiles were at the beginning in EPSG 102092.

Answer (score 2):

Google use Web Mercator.

EPSG:3857 formerly EPSG:900913

But Web Mercator is a interesting projection system. As it uses WGS84 for calculations.

So you can try EPSG:4326

Answer (score 2):

As you can see on sites like https://epsg.io/3857 or https://www.epsg-registry.org/ , EPSG:3857 uses the World Geodetic System 1984 (WGS84) as datum.